# How to change password of a database in DB2 software of IBM?

Tags: database, db2, forgot-password

However, it seems very trivial - How to get the current username of  a database in DB2 software in IBM; But, trust me, when it comes to entering the database username and password while connecting DB2 with eclipse, you might have to wait for a time which is tediously long. **Let's get straight to the point**:-

This is how you get the username of a database in DB2.

1. open **DB2 Command Line Processor** .
2. Connect to your database:-

   ```
        db2 => connect to <database_name>
   ```
3. Enter this query in db2 clp:-

   ```
        db2 =>  SELECT CURRENT USER FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
   ```
4. You'll get the current user name of the current database that you have accessed.

Now, **the main problem is** :- How to get / change the password if one has forgotten the password. And, What is the difference between database password and the one that i entered while installing DB2 ?

Answer (score 11):

DB2 does not have its own set of IDs and passwords; it relies on the operating system to perform authentication.  So your ID and password are what you used to log in to Windows (or Linux, AIX, etc); and you change your password as you do normally on each platform.

The password you entered during installation is for a different ID - DB2 created a new user on your local machine.  On Windows the ID is called `db2admin` by default.

Answer (score 2):

```
db2 "CONNECT TO <database> USER <userid> USING <password> NEW <new_password> CONFIRM <new_password>"
```

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21984232

Comment: That requires Transparent LDAP.